# Toggling a css class to show/hide overflow does not re-show the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This jsfiddle should show my problem (or run the attached snippet): https://jsfiddle.net/gx9ohkuv/26/

I'm using bootstrap's badge class, which has `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` properties, and my own hide-overflow class to show/hide overflow in a div with a set width.

When the overflow gets hidden then expanded again, it doesn't re-show the previously hidden content.

Is there a way to fix this without having to do something like remove the elements from the dom?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showAll = true;
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    showAll = !showAll;
    if (showAll) {
      $('#container').removeClass('hide-overflow');
    } else {
      $('#container').addClass('hide-overflow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em .4em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.badge-secondary {
  color: white;
  background-color: #6c757d;
}
.hide-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="container" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px;">
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1001</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1002</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1003</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1004</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1005</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1006</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1007</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1008</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1009</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Devils advocate.  Why not just use the `toggleClass('hide-overflow')` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding some styles to your element while adding the class, but that element doesn't have a default value.

add the next code before the toggle class

```
#container{
    text-overflow: initial;
    word-wrap: initial;
    }
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showAll = true;
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    showAll = !showAll;
    if (showAll) {
      $('#container').removeClass('hide-overflow');
    } else {
      $('#container').addClass('hide-overflow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em .4em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.badge-secondary {
  color: white;
  background-color: #6c757d;
}

#container {
  text-overflow: initial;
  word-wrap: initial;
}

.hide-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="container" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px;">
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1001</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1002</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1003</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1004</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1005</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1006</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1007</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1008</span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">span 1009</span>
</div>
```